# How to forward www and non www .net to www .com?

Tags: .htaccess

I can forward the www .net URL to the www .com. But how can I forward the non www .net to the www .com?

The code below is what I am using in the .htaccess file and it is partially working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please be more clear as to what you want. Do you want all requests that hit this directory to get redirected to `www.example.com`?

Comment: Exactly. I want anything that goes to example.net or www.example.net to go to www.example.com

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I just said. You are limiting it to `example.net` and `www.example.net`.

Comment: Not sure why I was dinged for my question. I think the subject line is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Why don't just do the opposite in .htaccess in www.example.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your comment, it looks like what you are actually asking for is anything addressed to `*.example.net` or `example.net` to be forwarded to www.example.com. The way to do this would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.example\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There might be a fancy way to do it with regexp instead of two conditions, but I would suggest this is the simplest and most straightforward way of doing it.

Comment: This is only my second question on Stack. I'm just curious but why did I receive 2 down votes for my question?